# Declare a module in the current namespace for use with `module->exports`

Tags: module, namespaces, racket

I would like to use the function `module->exports` to find all of the exports provided by a module. Unfortunately, the module passed to that function must be declared in the current namespace before the function can be used on it. When I know what the module is statically this is no problem, I just require it into the current module and then use the function.

However, if I don't know the module statically, and am passed in a module path index (that I know points to a valid module in the filesystem), I can't seem to get the module declared into the current namespace. Say if I want to make a module-path-index->exports function:

```
(define (module-path-index->exports mpi)
  (parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
    <stuff to load module path index into current-namespace>
    (if (module-declared? mpi)
        (module->exports mpi)
        (error "Module not declared"))))
```

Any suggestions on how to declare the module?

Update:

I can't just use `namespace-reaquire` here, as it seems to fail with `module-path-index`s that come from the `identifier-binding` function. For example, the following code:

```
#lang racket

(define binding (identifier-binding #'contract-continuation-mark-key))

(parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
  (dynamic-require (first binding) (void))
  (module->exports (first binding)))
```

gives this error:

```
Language: racket, with debugging; memory limit: 8192 MB.
. . require: unknown module
  module name: #<resolved-module-path:"/Users/leif/racket/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/guts.rkt">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close! But you need to resolve the module path index `(first binding)`. The function that does this is [resolve-module-path-index](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/module-helpers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fmodresolve..rkt%29._resolve-module-path-index%29%29) from [syntax/modresolve](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/module-helpers.html#%28mod-path._syntax%2Fmodresolve%29).

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/modresolve)

(define binding (identifier-binding #'contract-continuation-mark-key))

(parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
  (define resolved (resolve-module-path-index (first binding) (current-directory)))
  (dynamic-require resolved (void))
  (module->exports resolved))
```